# MySQL find all null values in a DB

Tags: mysql, database, null, find

I apologize in advance if I missed the solution in my search.

I've found NULL values scattered throughout the Database I'm testing.

I am able to find all null values in a table, the issue is the DB I'm testing has 517 tables so the following query structure will not work, adding the columns as I did is impossible for that amount of tables

```
select 
    *
from
    Table
where
    tbl_column1 or tbl_column2 or tbl_column3 or tbl_column4
    is null
```

Is this workable in MySQL, how would I find  all null values

I can get all column instances using

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('tbl_column1','tbl_column2')
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='DBwithManyTables';
```

Is something like this part of the solution?

Any ideas for how to do this?

Comment: Which column ur checking for?

Comment: @Venk I think that's the point - all of them

Answer (score 0):

You could *possibly* do this with some modifications to the script found here: http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=232

You would probably have to change this line...

```
'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @CNT_VALUE FROM `',table_schema,'`.`',table_name,'` WHERE `', column_name,'` REGEXP ''',in_search,''';'
```

...to be like this...

```
'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @CNT_VALUE FROM `',table_schema,'`.`',table_name,'` WHERE `', column_name,'` IS NULL''';'
```

...and you'll probably have to also do some other modifications but I believe using that script as your foundation will lead you to the information you're looking for.